# Make switch case as a generic case

Tags: switch-statement

I have more than 50 cases in switch statement. I don't want to write each case one by one and all cases are doing the same work. I want to make a generic case which do the work for all. This code is for unity. I want to know how we used case as a generic?

Basically this code is for displaying image one by one per clicks mean per click it shows the different image. Please help me how can I make it generic. It give error in case 'i'.

Here is my code:

```
for (int j = 0; j != Gallery.Length; j++)
{
    switch (i)
    {
        *case 'i':*
        displayimage.sprite = Gallery[i];
        i++;
        break;

        default:
        Debug.Log("Muzaffar");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I actually don't see a problem here.  The `for` loop determines the value of `i`, which then determines the image.  Why do you think you need a `switch` statement here?

Comment: i understand there is no need of switch statement there but that my task is to make the cases generic instead of regular multiple cases. do you have any idea about generic case? @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0):

Here example:

```
        Sprite[] Gallery;
        //SelectedSprite - can be string type variable, for selecting case.
        Sprite SelectedSprite;

        for (int i = 0; i < Gallery.Length; i++)
        {
             displayimage.sprite = SelectedSprite.name == Gallery[i].name ? Gallery[i].sprite : null;
        }
```